# Search for multiple terms in multiple columns

Tags: php, sql, search

I have a search form that searches for users names. The problem is, in my database, I have a separate firstname and lastname collumn. This is how my query currently looks like (this is inside a PHP script, and $term is the search input):

```
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE firstname LIKE '%$term%' OR lastname LIKE '%$term%'
```

This works fine when the user only enter either a firstname or a lastname, but for full names such as "John Smith", this won't work.

How can I modify my query and/or php script to efficiently fix this problem? For example, should I split the string first, or etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
WHERE firstname||' '||lastname LIKE '%$term%'
```

That comparares firstname plus a space plus last name against `%$term%`.

However, you shouldn't be building SQL queries with variables.  You should use parametrized queries through PDO.  See http://bobby-tables.com/php.html for examples.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me. I'm now using MATCH and AGAINST but there's the disadvantage that the term "artin" will not show "Martin" amongst the results, but at least "marti" does. Yeah I'm not using PDO just to make it simple, i usually use mysqli prepared statements :)

Comment: But you're not using prepared statements, or if you are, you're not doing it correctly because you're building your SQL statements from variables outside your program.

Comment: I know. I "usually" use prepared statements, but I'm not using it here just because I can't be bothered to and because it doesn't make a difference to what I want to know: the query structure